# Retrofit2 calls for viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, retrofit2, call

I have created a viewpager with 2 fragments (fragmentA et fragmentB). For each fragment, I have to call a specific service with retrofit2 to get some datas. For example, for the **fragmentA** I want to get data about film and for the **fragmentB** information about TV shows.

To do that, I call service1 in the oncreateView in fragmentA and service2 in the oncreateView in fragmentB. When I launch my app, no problem for the fragmentA I receive all the film but my fragmentB is empty.

Have you an answer about this issue? Maybe it's a cache issue or maybe I have to call service1 and service 2 in the activity that contains the viewpager?

I hope, it's ok for my explanations

Comment: Test case : `mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);` / 2

Comment: can you please share your code

Comment: @war_Hero which part of my code? fragmentA, B or only one fragment? because it's the same code, except service calls.

Comment: @VishvaDave can you explain me, what is the goal of this function?

Comment: post the view pager,adapter,any fragment or both

Comment: @RudySchoepfer It will load data of both fragment at once.. when viewpager attached the adapter.. so there will be no issue for next fragment service call.. try it once and let me know if any problem

Comment: @VishvaDave your solution doesn't work.... My 2 fragments are empty if I put (0) or (2) and if I put (1) I have the same result than before.

Comment: @war_Hero I will share my code soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the problem was not the dual call but the response of my api.
SO I directly manipulate the api code in Symfony and now it' ok.
Thanks for your advise.